# Parameterized commands in javascript or php

Tags: php, javascript, security, prepared-statement, parameterization

Is it possible to have parameterized commands or prepared statements in javascript or php. I see it is possible in java and in database queries? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of PHP - yes. See [PDO tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) for the example

Speaking of JS, you have to understand that it is impossible with **client-side** javascript, but with some server-side version it is quite possible too.

Comment: So when we say prepared statement or parameterized commands we only mean in the context of querying the database. Can't prepared statements be for PHP commands, which may fall prey to malicious input(for example user gives php code as input) that may execute the attack. Sorry new to this so just wanted to clarify.

Comment: Generally speaking - yes, we are using the term only in the context of querying database. If your question is out of idle curiosity, this answer is enough. If you have more certain question or a task to perform, you are welcome to ask.